# How can I distribute portlet pages to different environments automatically?

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, portlet

I'm a newbie developing a liferay 6.1 portlet. I want a static url and static content in the page where my portlet will be. What methods are recommended and available for distributing the portlet and page to different environments?

I want all environments to match as exactly as possible and I prefer to have everything automated, so I would like the page creation automatic too.

Comment: Just be careful when you are explaining stuff regarding Liferay. "Layout" in Liferay means a template to place a portlets in Liferay site's "Page".  Are you on correct track??

Comment: @aston The terminology is very, very confusing to me and I tried to be careful and very simple in my explanation because of that. I want to create what looks to the browser like a single page with one single content on it. I want that page to have a single static URL too, all it's operations will be with ajax. So essentially yeah, create a single new page or update if it already exists. Did I mess up my terms?

Comment: Yes, this is possible - but before I post an answer, I would like to know, why can't you add the page and your portlet with the UI? You call it _easier autodeploys_, but if you change your portlet the changes will be visible _without_ rebuilding the page.

Comment: @TobiasLiefke Good catch, by autodeploys I meant that when this will be installed to various dev environments and then staging/testing/production I wanted this portlet to be as automatic as possible. We are using puppet and other tools so I think I could automate it there maybe or just do it by hand too. Also, I dislike doing anything by hand if I can avoid it.

Comment: Maybe you should have asked for exactly that: _How can I distribute my pages to different environments?_ - My answer would have been to use _LAR_ Export/Import (can be done automatically as well) or _resources importer_. Because there is usually more than just adding the portlet.

Comment: @TobiasLiefke Ah, so it was a classic XY problem. Yeah I have never heard of either of those. Edited the question!

Comment: As I didn't answered your original question: You can access and modify nearly everything in Liferay using the appropriate `...LocalServiceUtil` methods. For creating a page that would be `LayoutLocalServiceUtil.addLayout`. But that shouldn't be necessary anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the *resources importer*, a documentation for that can be found in the [Liferay Developer Network: Creating plugins to share structures, templates and more](https://dev.liferay.com/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/6-2/creating-plugins-to-share-structures-templates-and-more).

Or you create a *LAR file* by exporting your pages - again described in the [Liferay Developer Network: Export/Import](https://dev.liferay.com/discover/portal/-/knowledge_base/6-2/export-import).

You can import a LAR file from the UI or with the following code:

```
public void importPages() {
    // Define the settings for import - here some examples:
    final Map<String, String[]> params = new HashMap<>();
    addParam(params, PortletDataHandlerKeys.PORTLET_USER_PREFERENCES, true);
    addParam(params, PortletDataHandlerKeys.PORTLET_USER_PREFERENCES_ALL, true);
    addParam(params, PortletDataHandlerKeys.PORTLET_CONFIGURATION, true);
    addParam(params, PortletDataHandlerKeys.PORTLET_CONFIGURATION_ALL, true);
    addParam(params, PortletDataHandlerKeys.PORTLET_ARCHIVED_SETUPS, true);
    addParam(params, PortletDataHandlerKeys.PORTLET_ARCHIVED_SETUPS_ALL, true);
    addParam(params, PortletDataHandlerKeys.PORTLET_DATA, true);
    addParam(params, PortletDataHandlerKeys.PORTLET_DATA_ALL, true);
    addParam(params, PortletDataHandlerKeys.PORTLET_SETUP, true);
        addParam(params, PortletDataHandlerKeys.PORTLET_SETUP_ALL, true);
    addParam(params, PortletDataHandlerKeys.PORTLET_DATA_CONTROL_DEFAULT, true);

    addParam(params, PortletDataHandlerKeys.THEME_REFERENCE, true);
    addParam(params, PortletDataHandlerKeys.LAYOUT_SET_SETTINGS, true);
    addParam(params, PortletDataHandlerKeys.LOGO, true);

    addParam(params, PortletDataHandlerKeys.CATEGORIES, true);
    addParam(params, PortletDataHandlerKeys.RATINGS, true);
    addParam(params, PortletDataHandlerKeys.COMMENTS, true);

    addParam(params, PortletDataHandlerKeys.DELETE_MISSING_LAYOUTS, true);
    addParam(params, PortletDataHandlerKeys.DELETIONS, true);
    addParam(params, PortletDataHandlerKeys.DELETE_PORTLET_DATA, true);

    addParam(params, PortletDataHandlerKeys.USER_ID_STRATEGY, UserIdStrategy.CURRENT_USER_ID);
    addParam(params, PortletDataHandlerKeys.DATA_STRATEGY, PortletDataHandlerKeys.DATA_STRATEGY_MIRROR);

    addParam(params, PortletDataHandlerKeys.PERMISSIONS, true);

    // Import with the current user into the current site (= group)
    ThemeDisplay themeDisplay = (ThemeDisplay) getPortletRequest().getAttribute(WebKeys.THEME_DISPLAY)
    LayoutLocalServiceUtil.importLayouts(themeDisplay.getUserId(), themeDisplay.getHostGroupId(), false, params, inputStreamOfMyLARFile);
}

// Helper method
private static void addParam(final Map<String, String[]> params, final String key, final Object value) {
    params.put(key, new String[] { value.toString() });
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but that seems just ridiculous or I'm failing to think about this correctly. To reiterate; I want to create a page and insert a portlet there when my portlet gets installed - how does either of those help? The LAR looks like it's for importing/exporting data, which seems useless for my scenario, unless I'm thinking of it wrong. Is there even a way to fire `importPages()`? How? Does either really create a site page? I can't see that bit at all. Where do I define the name? `LayoutLocalServiceUtil.addLayout` looks like my best bet, but how can I fire even that?

Comment: Hah, even the link in Import/Export LR documentation to something that would seem a little relevant; 'Creating and Managing Pages' is broken.

Comment: I can't see the link you have mentioned, but entering _Creating and Managing Pages_ into the search of the Liferay Developer Network I found [this as the first hit](https://dev.liferay.com/discover/portal/-/knowledge_base/6-1/creating-sites-and-managing-pages) - which seems to work.

Comment: To your first comment: In your original question you didn't asked how to fire your "create a page and insert a portlet action" - so I assumed that this part is known to you already. You would call _importPages_ at the exactly same position. LAR files can contain many things, including exactly one page with one portlet. Just create a site with exactly your page and portlet and go to _Admin_ - _Site Administration_ - _Pages_ - _Public Pages_ - _Export_

Comment: I 've created a post to answer how you could fire what ever you like as soon as your plugin is started: [How can I run some action when my plugin was deployed to Liferay](/questions/31046786)